# When inheriting from a base class, what happens with nested classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, try-catch, nested-class

Say I have these classes:

```
class Base
{
    public:

        class Foo { ... };

        ...
};
```

Then another class derives from the base:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    // no mention or redefinition of nested class "Foo" anywhere in "Derived"
};
```

Does this mean we now have a distinct `Derived::Foo`, or is `Derived::Foo` the exact same as `Base::Foo`?

Here is a twist on this scenario:  what if someone throws an instance of `Derived::Foo`?  Would it be caught in this scenario:

```
catch ( const Base::Foo &ex )
{
    // would this also catch an instance of Derived::Foo?
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Derived::Foo` is just accessing `Base::Foo`, therefore these are just two ways to refer to the same type. You can easily check it with [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base
{
    class Foo {};
};

struct Derived : Base {};

static_assert( std::is_same< Base::Foo, Derived::Foo >::value, "Oops" );

int main()
{
    try {
        throw Derived::Foo();
    }
    catch( const Base::Foo& ) {}
}
```

As you can see, this also means throwing it by one name and catching it by the other works as well.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/804689622d87914b)

Answer (score 3):

`Base::Foo` and `Derived::Foo` are indeed the same *type*, a class is just a *compound type*(from the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `3.9.2`) and we would not expect a *type* inherited from a *base class* to be a different type in the *derived class*. For example if `Base` contained:

```
typedef int newType1 ;
```

as long as `Derived` did not redeclare `newType1` then we would expect `Base::newType1` and `Derived::newType1` to be the same *type* and a *nested class* is no different. If we refer to the draft standard section `9.2` *Class members* paragraph *1* says(*emphasis mine*):

> [...]**Members of a class are** data members, member functions (9.3), **nested types**, and
>   enumerators. Data members and member functions are static or non-static; see 9.4. **Nested types are
>   classes (9.1, 9.7) and enumerations (7.2) defined in the class, and arbitrary types declared as members by use of a typedef declaration (7.1.3)**.

That confirms that intuition *nested classes* are just *types*(and also members), for completeness sake section `9.7` referenced above is the *nested class* section and from section `10` *Derived classes* paragraph *1* we see:

> [...]Unless redeclared in the derived class, members of a base class are also considered to be members of the derived class.[...]

Since they are the same type the *catch* will work fine.